# Is it a duplicate if the question was asked on another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I recently ran across this [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/15563/959), which was suggested as being a duplicate of this [question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/860) on [Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/).

While the answer provided at another Stack Exchange site is an useful reference, does it really make sense to label this question as a duplicate? It doesn't show up in the search, so for someone posting, there's really no way for them to know it's a "duplicate". Is there a difference between "duplicate" and "exact duplicate" that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3):

No, you're not missing anything.

Some Stack Exchange sites have overlap in their site scopes, and that's just fine.

What we want to make sure is that questions that are asked on different stacks are tailored to the specific communities that they are asked in. Copy/paste from one site to another doesn't work. However, often a question on say Biblical Hermeneutics has aspects that are appropriate for the textual scholars there, but also for the doctrinal scholars here. In that case you get different answers in each community.

What I'd ask is that a question that is asked in both places indicate how it's tailored to each community.

In this particular case, since the OP of the question here is asking about a specific meaning of a specific wording in a specific passage, I'd argue that while it's not completely off topic here, it's much much more on topic on BH.SE and there is no tailoring of the question here to our audience. It's already been shipped over there and that's the right move here.

Answer (score 2):

Technically no.

Each site has a different scope and focus. Technically there is some overlap, but the same question can expect rather different answers on each site. The possibility of deliberately asking on both sites was recently raised here:

[Can something be asked both here and on BH.se?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1458/30)

As far as innocently asking on one site without even knowing about the other, I think the general rule is that they should be given a green light. If you do know  of a related question on the other site I can think of several useful things to do:

- Commenting with a link so the related question on the other site is certainly called for.
- If the gist of the question is really duplicated, asking the OP if the other question handles there case would be a place to start.
- I said "start" just now because the next step would be to tweak the question here to be more specific to a Christian audience. Turning exegesis questions around and asking specifically about Christian teachings stemming from a verse is a viable way to handle questions that would otherwise be covering repeat ground.

When people ask for exegesis of a verse on this site, _what they should be wanting is what doctrines Christianity derives from a verse, not what a correct interpretation would be. [We don't do truth questions anyway](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1380/30). On BH, answers can compete for the best argument for interpreting a verse inclusive of non Christian doctrinal frameworks.

**Update:** In the case of the question you linked, the OP later clarified that they were most interested in specifically the original Jewish understanding of a the text. That is clearly off topic for this site, but on topic for BH, so I have migrated this question there and marked it as a duplicate.

The issue in this case was not so much that the question was duplicate but that the question the OP was trying to ask was completely off topic for this site in the first place.